# Slow upload speeds on windows 7 only

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, performance, upload

I have had some issue's since i've changed network cards, previously used a killer network card, now back to the on-board card, my download speed is absolutely fine, no issue, only my upload speed is effected, things such as FTP and also things like gmail are very slow due to the limited upload.

I am wondering, how do I go about troubleshooting this?

I know the problem is not hardware/cable as I have booted a linux live cd and this is getting the speedtest results I would expect (around 9meg up), however in windows speedtest takes forever at the upload stage and ftp is only getting about 900 bytes upload speed..

I have never encountered anything like this.

Comment: some extra info, this windows installation is less than a month old, I always virus scan downloaded files and my anti-spyware hasn't found anything of note either (just some cookies).

Comment: Why not switch back to the killer card? It can't be as expensive as troubleshooting the on-board one.

Comment: because the killer card was only getting 10mbit down instead of 120, also the troubleshooting is windows, not the card.

Answer (score 1):

So the killer card isn't fast under Windows when receiving data? The Live CD works great sending and receiving? The standard Windows advice applies; make sure you have the latest driver, check all the various device settings in Windows, reinstall the driver. You could try something like Wireshark to see if there are things like retransmits or whatnot, but I'm not sure what you can do about it if the driver is causing the problem. If there are older versions of the Windows device driver, you could try those. There really isn't much you can do if the Windows driver needs fixing except complain to the manufacturer or switch to hardware that uses a different driver.

Comment: the killer card was fast at uploading but slow at downloading, onboard card is the opposite, i'm going to try the steps from    http://www.lamnk.com/blog/computer/reset-tcpip-networking-stack-in-windows-7-and-vista/   and  http://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/show/298-completely-rebuild-the-tcp-ip-stack.